# Unable to send data to FPDF

Tags: html, mysql, reference, fpdf

I have a php page called *page2.php* which is connected to database via *conectionDB.php* and *uploadChannel1.php* to upload images. I have html page *channel1.html* where my form is.

But I need to send the input to FPDF to print it or save it, but this error keeps showing

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file'

I used *ob_start* and *ob_flush* and *ob_clean* and others but still not working I know the problem is with my php code. Please guys help me in this one.

```
require 'connectionDB.php';
require 'channel1.html';
require 'uploadChannel1.php';

 if(isset($_POST['stdName']) && isset($_POST['secondGrand'])&& isset($_POST['grandName']) && isset($_POST['fatherAName']) && isset($_POST['motherGrand']) && isset($_POST['motherFatherName']) && isset($_POST['motherName']) && isset($_POST['subjectNum']) && isset($_POST['TotalNum'])&& isset($_POST['Avg']) && isset($_POST['birthDate']) && isset($_POST['gender']) && isset($_POST['stdType'])&& isset($_POST['jobs']) && isset($_POST['city'])&& isset($_POST['phone'])&& isset($_POST['bookDate'])&& isset($_POST['bookNo']))
 {
    $student=sanitizeString($_POST['stdName']);
    $grand2=sanitizeString($_POST['secondGrand']); 
    $grand1=sanitizeString($_POST['grandName']);
    $father=sanitizeString($_POST['fatherAName']);  
     $motherGrand=sanitizeString($_POST['motherGrand']);
     $motherFather=sanitizeString($_POST['motherFatherName']); 
     $mother=sanitizeString($_POST['motherName']); 
     $subNo= sanitizeString($_POST['subjectNum']);
     $Total=sanitizeString($_POST['TotalNum']);
     $avg=sanitizeString($_POST['Avg']);
     $graduateDate=sanitizeString($_POST['graduateYear']);
     $birth=sanitizeString($_POST['birthDate']);
     $gender=sanitizeString($_POST['gender']);
     $job=sanitizeString($_POST['jobs']);
     $stdType=sanitizeString($_POST['stdType']);
     $City=sanitizeString($_POST['city']);
     $tel=sanitizeString($_POST['phone']);
     $bookdate=sanitizeString($_POST['bookDate']);
     $bookNum=sanitizeString($_POST['bookNo']);

     if(!empty($student) &&!empty($grand2) &&!empty($grand1) &&!empty($father)&&!empty($motherGrand)&&!empty($motherFather)&&!empty($mother)&&!empty($subNo)&&!empty($Total)&&!empty($avg)&&!empty($graduateDate)&&!empty($birth)&&!empty($gender)&&!empty($stdType)&&!empty($City)&&!empty($tel) && !empty($bookdate) &&!empty($bookNum) &&!empty($job))
     {
         session_start();
         $_SESSION['stdName] =$studen ;
         }
.......
```